# SVG shifts position on rotating

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, accordion

I've fiddled with a pure CSS accordion during the last few days. Essentially I have no clue what I'm doing, however I found a few examples that pushed me in the right direction. I now got it working. Well almost!

*Before you read any further, I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/theLuca/pen/MWYJNGG). I thought it might be helpful to be able to check the code I'm talking about. You know, I'm trying to help you helping me ...*

The accordion has an circular SVG Element which I wrapped in a `<label>` tag to use for expanding and collapsing the accordion. On clicking the SVG (or actually the label) a `radio` input get‘s checked which in turn starts an animation that `transform: rotate(45deg);` the SVG. It also triggers the expanding of the row. There is also some more trickery involving a second `radio` input in each row to be able to use the SVG for collapsing the row again.

I think (hope) these details you just read are not relevant for my actual problem! But maybe they are so I wanted to provide some context. Anyways, it seemed to be [the effect I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f84EP.gif) when I just fiddled with it in a document without proper:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
<body>
```

But as soon as I added these the animation changed and now, additionally to the rotation the SVG also slightly *shifts position* (down and to the right if I'm not mistaken). So this is [the effect I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrzpn.gif)!

What is that effect I`m seeing? Is it because the the rotating element, which is actually the label, is square not round? So then why does it only happen when the HTML is formatted properly?

In case it's important, the GIFS are recorded in Safari (which I also use to preview the code). But the [codepen](https://codepen.io/theLuca/pen/MWYJNGG) also shows the *shifting*. I'm probably searching the wrong term but I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: The problem you have is the fact that the label is too height. Use `label{height:30px; width:30px; display:inline-block;padding:0;` to fix the problem. An other comment is that you ate using the same svg many times. I would use `use` elements not to repeat all the code so many times.

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you that fixed it! Also I looked into the `use` elements! Much better than actually repeating the SVG each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First advice - don't forget to set x and y position for an absolute elements, that could cause a problems in some browsers. And your problem was in `label` (`faq-btn`), because it is a rectangle, but for good animation it should be a square.

Here is the fix of two classes:

```
.faq-row {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.faq-btn {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 400px;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: I think I'll use the solution of @enxaneta, but this works as well. Is there any up- or downside to the respective solutions? Also **big thank you** for not just providing a solution but also explaining what caused the problem in the first place!

Comment: @theLuca glad, that you solved your problem. Well, the advantage of this solution is that you won't need to specify a static size for your wrapper, so the label will take a size of `svg`, but for some cases it might be better to set exact `height` and `width`. It depends on context.